# Downloading image from internet losses transparency

Tags: android

When I download a image from internet and I save to the sdcard, the image has a black background when the original images hasn't

```
httpRequest = new HttpGet(fileUrl);
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
 InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
 Bitmap    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
 String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"basquetMobile-  images";
 File dir = new File(file_path);     
 if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
 File file = new File(dir, tipoImagen+idEquipo+".jpg");
 FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
 bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fOut);
 fOut.flush();
 fOut.close();
```

Thanks for the help!!

**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[SOLUTION]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>**

change:

File file = new File(dir, tipoImagen+idEquipo+"**.png**");

**bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);**

**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>THANKS!<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>**

Comment: the layout or the imageview hasn't have a background color or anything

Comment: I don't think JPEG supports transparency, no?

Comment: if I change the background color to any color in the image, the image download correctly and I put in the drawable folder the transparency appears

Comment: I put result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, fOut); and the is the same

Comment: Perhaps you do not want to compress? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: And how y can save it without compress?

Comment: @benoffi7: bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fOut);   change to 100, it happen for all of image or just one?

Comment: all images... I tried (Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut) and (Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut) and nothing...

Answer (score 3):

change:

File file = new File(dir, tipoImagen+idEquipo+".png");

bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);